# $n \mid a^n-1 \Rightarrow n^2 \mid a^n-1$ for all $a$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

A positive integer $n$ is said to have property $P$ if $n|a^n-1$ implies $n^2|a^n-1$. Prove that: 
a) All primes have property $P$. 
b) There are infinitely many composite numbers which have the property $P$. 
I have already solved the problem a. In problem b, I tried set $n=p^2$ and $n=pq$ with $p,q$ are primes but I have got stuck at $a^p \equiv 1$ (mod $p^2$) and $a^q \equiv 1$ (mod $p$). 
I have found a solution on AoPS but is seems to be wrong. 
Link that solution: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1194856p5846189 
In that solution, I don't agree that order of $a$ mod $p$ is $\phi(p)=p-1$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the AoPS proof?  Why do you think it is wrong?  If you show how far you have gone, it is easier to see what the next step is.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: You should summarize the AoPS proof so your question is self contained.  You should still link to it so people can find where this comes from.  You should then point out what step you think is wrong so we can focus on that.

Answer (score 1):

Comment:

Particular case:

It can be shown that $n^2|a^n-1$ if $a=n+1$:

This solution is from 'number theory' by Sierpinski:

We use binomial expansion:

$$(n+1)^n=1+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}n^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot\binom{n}{n}n^n$$

For n>1 all terms, from third term, $n\geq 2$ and also $\binom{n}{1}n=n^2$, Hence $n^2|(n+1)^n-1$. This true for any number including when n is primes. So if $a=n+1$ we may write:

$n^2|a^n-1\Leftrightarrow n|a^n-1$

Update: We may say that generaly if $a=kn+1$ then $n^2|a^n-1\Leftrightarrow n|a^n-1$ and argue that any number (odd or even) can be written as $a=kn+1$ such that:

$n^2|a^n-1\Leftrightarrow n|a^n-1$

Comment: Why you can choose $a=n+1$ although the problem is "for all $a$" ?

Comment: I said this is a particular case.

Comment: Ok I understood. Thanks very much !